# NgbModal's @Input and local variable

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

We are using NgbModal, and based on the sample found here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples, name is referenced
`modalRef.componentInstance.name` via the @Input decorator (i.e. `@Input() name`) in the modal. I tried removing the @Input decorator, and it still works.

See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szwhfq?file=src/app/modal-component.ts

Can anyone provide an explanation why is this so?

Thank you.

Comment: May you please provide the link to the modal documentation stating the need for the @Input decorator? I would create an issue to change those docs. Or you can do it yourself: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues

Comment: I meant code sample sorry about that. Please see Components as content sample in the https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples. I've edited my question to reflect this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Input` decorator allows us to pass the properties through the HTML template. code `<my-component myProp='123'></my-component>` would not pass the value of the `myProp` if `myProp` declared without the `@Input` decorator.

Modal doesn't work with the template. It uses the instance of the component (which is shown in the modal) the same way as we use services or DTOs. No passing data in the template - no need for the `@Input` decorator.